# MATLAB Symprod? Need to return a function that a product series should return

Tags: matlab

So Im trying to calculate how to compute Newtons Forward Difference method for a unit in uni, and its the last question on this group assignment I need to complete.

It's hard to explain really what it does without writing a couple paragraphs, but it generally interpolates polynomial functions, and returns a function, in other words you provide some X and Y coordinates you know this function should pass through, and it will return some function that really closely approximates the actual function, and does pass through those points. So really useful stuff.

Anyway...
I have a massive function that this all gets plugged in to, but what Im having trouble with is returning a function from a product series.

The series is something like...

```
s(s-1)(s-2)...(s-n+1) %Not coded obviously
```

Where,

```
s = @(x) (x - X(1))/h;
```

So s is a function of x, and Im trying to get the function of that series in terms of x. Any help would be highly appreciated.

My attempt is this:

```
func = @(x) Y(1) + symprod(s*(s-n+1)) ./ factorial(n);
```

Includes a few extra things I havn't mentioned, but it still involves my attempt at getting a function in terms of s for the product series...

n is just an integer, known value.

Even after using isolate function as suggested below, still no result. Not really sure what to do, someone hellpp

Comment: Your call to `symprod` is not even right, the function takes 2 or 4 arguments.

Comment: n is a known value, if that helps, and I dont understand how to use symprod, it was my only attempt at getting this right, but I dont understand how to do it properly, if you can help that would be great.

Comment: Well, this shoudl give you syntax error. Go to the documentation, read it.

Comment: I realise that, but I still get issues, this isnt solved. I tried with syms, but the symprod doenst provide a useable function still that I can interpret

Comment: Its not clear what you want and you posted wrong code, so we can not help. Post a [mcve] and an explanation of what you want

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this out, so I never actually ended up getting the above method to work, wherein I was trying to get a function from a bunch of variables, and an infinite product series, I ended up just using a for loop to simulate the product infinite series, got that value, and then when I wanted a function I simply wrote f = @(x) value_from_function(x).

For an example of some working code, I uploaded it on my [GitHub](https://github.com/Realmm/Newtons-Forward-Difference-MATLAB/blob/master/interpolating_polynomial.m)...

So, in that example I would do

```
f = @(x) interpolating_polynomial(X, Y, x);
```